# MySQL select row with two matching joined rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

Hey I try to select a row from a table with two matching entries on another one.
The structure is as following:

```
-----------------   ---------------------
| messagegroups |   | user_messagegroup |
|               |   |                   |
| - id          |   | - id              |
| - status      |   | - user_id         |
|               |   | - messagegroup_id |
-----------------   |                   |
                    ---------------------
```

There exist two rows in user_messagegroup with the ids of two users and both times the same messagegroup_id.
I would like to select the messagegroup where this two users are inside.

I dont get it.. so I would appreciate some help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification you provide isn't very clear.

You say "with the ids of two users"... if we take that to mean you have two user_id values you want  to supply in the query, then one way to to find the messagegroups that contain these two specific users:

```
SELECT g.id
     , g.status
  FROM messagegroups g
  JOIN ( SELECT u.messagegroup_id
           FROM user_messagegroup u
          WHERE u.user_id IN (42, 11)
          GROUP BY u.messagegroup_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) = 2
       ) c
    ON c.messagegroup_id = g.id
```

The returned messagegroups could also contain other users, besides the two that were specified.

If you want to return messagegroups that contain ONLY these two users, and no other users...

```
SELECT g.id
     , g.status
  FROM messagegroups g
  JOIN ( SELECT u.messagegroup_id
           FROM user_messagegroup u
          WHERE u.user_id IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY u.messagegroup_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IF(u.user_id IN (42,11),u.user_id,NULL)) = 2
            AND COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) = 2
       ) c
    ON c.messagegroup_id = g.id
```

For improved performance, you'll want suitable indexes on the tables, and it may be possible to rewrite these to eliminate the inline view.

Also, if you only need the messagegroup_id value, you could get that from just the inline view query, without the need for the outer query and the join operation to the messagegroups table.